# How to find $F(x.t)\geq c|t|^{\mu}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have this condition
$$
0<\mu F(x, t) \leq t f(x, t), \text { for a.e } x \in \Omega, \quad 0<|t| \leq \gamma.
$$
where $F(x,t)=\int_0^t f(x,s) ds$.

I want to deduce that there exists $c>0$ such that

$$
 F(x, t) \geq c_{0}|t|^{\mu}, \quad \text { for a.e } x \in \Omega,|t| \leq \gamma.$$

I do this
\begin{align*}
\mu F(x,t)\leq t f(x,t)&\Rightarrow \dfrac{\mu}{t}\leq \dfrac{f(x,t)}{F(x,t)}\\
&\Rightarrow \int \dfrac{\mu}{t}\leq \int \dfrac{f(x,t)}{F(x,t)}\\
& \Rightarrow \mu\ln(|t|)+c\leq \ln(|F(x,t)|)  \\
&\Rightarrow c'|t|^{\mu}\leq |F(x,t)|
\end{align*}

How to delete the absulut value from F(x,t) ?

Comment: Is this Ambrosetti-Rabinowitz condition? Observe that $0 < \mu F$. Therefore, if $\mu>0$ then $F>0$.

Comment: Oh thank you I don't see it thank you very much